# Online collaborative team, connecting to 1 or more servers

Tags: vpn

I have a team of partners working from different locations in the world.
We all are connecting to our own VPS, as well as to a bunch of customers websites via http and ftp to other shared or vps servers.
In most of the above websites, there are ip filters restrictions.

I am looking for a way for my partners and me, to use a single IP to access these sites, so I can allow access to only that IP
I am also looking for this to be secure, when transferring data, ftp, sending passwords, etc, and also, if possible to have a reporting/monitoring console to see which partner connected where and when.

- Are there out there such services ?
- Is this something that can be achieved with a VPN service ?
- Any service providers recommendations ?

Comment: This is not a security SE question, you will be able to find a better response in the correct SE, but I believe that a proxy should do the trick. If you have an spare server you might use it and you will be able to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: oh I see..., I though it was relevant. Can you propose me the correct SE ?